# One to Many relationship always bring me empty

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, relationship

I try to use Entity Framework with code first and fluent api to implement a one to many relationship

I have two classes

```
namespace Mantenimiento.Business.Entities
{
    public class Personal : Entity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Dni { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }

        public string Cuil { get; set; }
        public string Legajo { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Dni")]
        public  ICollection<ContactoEmergencia> Contacto { get; set; }
}

namespace Mantenimiento.Business.Entities
{
    public class ContactoEmergencia : Entity
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? Dni { get; set; }
        public string ApellidoNombre { get; set; }
       public string Vinculo { get; set; }
        public string Domicilio { get; set; }
        public string telefono { get; set; }
        public string Comentario { get; set; }
        public int CreateUserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Dni")]
        public virtual Personal Personal { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my dbContext

```
            #region personals
            modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().ToTable("InfoPersonal").HasKey(t => t.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().Property(c => c.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn().IsRequired();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().Property(c => c.CreatedDate).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().Property(c => c.LastModifiedDate).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().Property(c => c.Deleted).HasDefaultValue(false);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().HasMany<ContactoEmergencia>(c => c.Contacto).WithOne(p => p.Personal).HasForeignKey(s => s.Dni);
#endregion
            #region contactoEmergencias
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactoEmergencia>().ToTable("InfoEmergencia").HasKey(d => d.Dni);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactoEmergencia>().Property(c => c.CreatedDate).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactoEmergencia>().Property(c => c.LastModifiedDate).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContactoEmergencia>().Property(c => c.Deleted).HasDefaultValue(false);
            #endregion
```

And my query is

```
        return await _context.personals
            .Include(c => c.Contacto)
            .Where(p => p.Deleted == false)
            .OrderBy(s => s.Apellido)
            .ToListAsync(

);
```

But the properties  is always empty.
i need to relate Personal.Di with Contacto.Dni, i had to change the key?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove ForeignKey attribute from Personal entity. In one to many relationship only child entity could accept ForeignKey.

Comment: i tried, but  it still brings me empty, should be change the key?, put in Personal Dni as a key?

Comment: ForeignKey just should be defined  in ContactoEmergencia  entity. Are you inserting any data?

Comment: yes i have 800 row in both table, the api fluent is ok, in personal the key should be Id or dni ?

Comment: In your model Personal only needs primary key that is id and it doesn't require any Foreign Key. Note to remove both  ForeignKey attribute and  fluent for ForeignKey from Personal entity.

Comment: Remove this:  modelBuilder.Entity<Personal>().HasMany<ContactoEmergencia>(c => c.Contacto).WithOne(p => p.Personal).HasForeignKey(s => s.Dni);

Comment: still not working, when i configure to be a relationships one to one it work ok but when a change to be one to many still bring me empty, i will try a relationships many to many

Comment: Why you are using both fluent api and data annotations for relationships? This can be error pone. In your case data annotation is enough.

Comment: Narges when i put         [ForeignKey("Dni")]
        public  virtual ICollection<ContactoEmergencia> Contacto { get; set; } in Personal Entity and remove public virtual personal personal from ContactoEmergencia, it work but jsut bring me one row inside of an array, if a add the virtual Personal in Contacto Emergencia it doesnt work, i dont understood why

Comment: Have you ever tried this query without LINQ to Entities? With sql query?